# Calling get (array static method) from an array instance

Tags: java, arrays, methods, static, instance

New to Java, and OOP in general.
I'm doing an online Lynda course, and in the course there's an example of using `Array.get` to extract the 2nd item from an array:

```
String[] myFavoriteCandyBars = {"Twix", "Hershey's", "Crunch"};
System.out.println(Array.get(myFavoriteCandyBars, 2));
```

And the instructor explained that get is a static method from the "Array" class.

But when I tried defining:

```
 `Array[] testarray = new Array[10];`
```

And using:

```
 `testarray.get(testarray[10]);`
```

I get an error:
    `cannot resolve method 'get(java.lang.reflect.Array)'`

But I don't understand why - the `testarray` is an object of class Array, and class Array has a method "get", so although it's bad practice, why can't I do it?

Comment: `Array.get(testarray, 10);` instead of `testarray.get(testarray[10]);`.

Comment: @goodvibration That's mildly incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) class is an internal Java class containing only public static methods, and its intended use is to not be be directly instantiated.  The following code:

```
testarray.get(testarray[10]);
```

fails because `testarray` is of type `Array[]`, not `Array`, and therefore does not have the static method `get()` available.  Hypothetically speaking, if you could call `Array#get` on an instance, it should work, but as mentioned above, `Array` cannot be instantiated.

A more typical way to use `Array` would be something like:

```
String[] testarray = new String[10];
testarray[1] = "Snickers";
System.out.println(Array.get(testarray, 1));
```

That is, create an array of the desired type, and then use `Array#get` to access whichever element you want.

Comment: I know that it's not suppose to  be used like that, but the thing is I CAN'T use it even when I try, and my questions is why?

the testarray is an object of class Array, and class Array has a method "get", so why doesn't it work?

Comment: `Array#get()` is a _static_ method, associated with the `Array` class, and _not_ with an instance of the `Array` class.  Review instance vs. static methods to better understand what is happening here.

Comment: but that is exactly my original question - "why can't I do it?".
of course I tried to review it before asking here. I looked at: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-methods-vs-instance-methods-java/
and in the end it says: "nstance method can access static variables and static methods directly."
and so I still don't know why it's not possible..

Comment: @guest2020 Your code can certainly be made to work, [see here](https://rextester.com/QEHQX56539), and also my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, looked at the Array definition and found that like you say - "Class Array is not instantiable" (says so in a comment): the constructor is in "private" and the new instance methods are static (Singleton). please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`get()` is not a method in the array class, (as in a byte[] object). `get()` is in the `Array` class. Doing `Array.get(testarray, 0)` is what you want. Despite that, don't do this, do `testarray[0]` instead.

Whenever you use a static method, you shouldn't call it from an object, you should use the class instance, so instead of doing

```
Object o = new Object();
o.staticMethod();
```

Do:

```
Object.staticMethod();
```